# PNG to SWF. Getting stuck exporting vectorized image to swf due to white gaps

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, png, swf

Complete newb here. Trying to vectorize some pngs with plans to convert to swf for a mobile app.  After image tracing and exporting to swf, I end up with white gaps in my swf.  Did a lot of google searching and reading of lots of forums, but still can't get rid of them.

Tried offset path, but that didn't work. Can't rasterize, because that means no more vector right?

Comment: Completely off-topic but what mobile app supports swf files?? Not iOS or Android I suspect.

Comment: @Luciano my developer uses Adobe Air.  Its a legacy app and I haven't ported to something better yet.

Comment: Can you post some of these png, a screenshot of the vector with gaps and the image tracing settings? But also, have you tried adjusting the image tracing settings?